# How can I update data object whenever changes happens inside v-for of child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I update data object of parent whenever changes happen inside v-for. I have a child component that I use inside parent component.

ParentComponent.vue

```
   <template>
       ....
       ....
    <child-component
      v-for="i in count"
      ref="childComponent"
      :key="i"
      currentPage="i"  // currentPage doesn't update.
      :page="i"
    />

      <q-header>
        {{currentPage}}  // always displays default value:1
      </q-header>

   </template>

    <script>
      data () {
         return {
            pageCount: 10,
            currentPage: 1,
          }
```

},

How can I update currentPage of data object whenever i changes inside v-for. I have tried using watch without much luck. I don't have access to child component and can't modify it.

Much appreciated!

Comment: `currentPage="i"` is passing string "i" into the prop. Use `:currentPage="i"` instead

Comment: Thanks @MichalLevý for the quick response. I still don't see currentPage getting updated. The value always remains 1, which is default.

Comment: It needs more information about what the child-component is actually doing. What is it you are trying to achieve ? It doesn't make much sense like this. You are going through a loop from 1 to 10, so you'll end up with with 10 child components, each with a locally scope "i" value from 1 to 10. It looks like you want to just assign i to currentPage, but you can't just apply 10 different value at once to it. There must be somekind of change event involved. what does q-header do  ?

Comment: I am trying to capture the value of "i" so I can update the value in the toolbar that belongs to parent component. e.g. when i is 5 I want to display 5 in the toolbar.

Comment: When and where do you mutate the value of `currentPage`?

Comment: Are you not able to simply use `i`? This will be the value of the current iteration so putting `{{ i }}` inside `<q-header>` will show what iteration number you are on

Comment: @Ollie q-header is outside the scope hence doesn't render value of 'i'

Answer (score 1):

There is some slight confusion with how `v-for` is working on the `child-component` here. Writing `currentPage="i"` as a property (which should actually be `v-bind:currentPage` in order for the `i` to be interpreted as JS) will simply declare the attribute on each `child-component`

> How can I update currentPage of data object whenever i changes inside v-for

`i` doesn't "change" in the traditional context of running a for loop inside of a normal JavaScript application. In Vue, your **rendering** logic and **application** logic are separate, and rightly so, because running logic as part of the rendering doesn't really make sense.

For example, let's look at how your app will render the `child-component`:

```html
<!-- Vue output -->
<child-component ... currentPage="1" />
<child-component ... currentPage="2" />
<child-component ... currentPage="3" />
```

So let's look at separating the **rendering** logic from the **application** logic.

I realise you don't have access to `child-component`, but based on the context I will assume it is some kind of tabbing functionality (based on you trying to set a value for the "current page" - feel free to be more specific and I can update my answer).

We need to bridge that gap between the rendering logic and the application logic and we can do that by using events:

```html
<child-component
  v-for="i in count"
  :ref="`childComponent-${i}`" // ref should be unique so add the i as part of it
  :key="i"
  :page="i"
  v-on:click="currentPage = i" // when the user clicks this child component, the current page will be updated
/>
```

You may have to utilise a different event other than `click` but I hope this gets you closer to what you are trying to achieve. For the value of `currentPage` to update there has to be some kind of user input, so just find out which event makes the most sense. Maybe the `child-component` library you are using has custom events that are more appropriate.

Comment: You got the problem accurately. Child component do render multiple times when page is loaded. I observed in Vue dev tools that, If `count` is 10 there are 10 child components with 10 different keys. Child component renders "page-loaded" event for each page which I could use to change the value of current page.

My use case is that when I scroll on the child component, I want to update the toolbar about that which child component I am on. e.g. if I have 10 child components and I scroll to child component 5, I want to show page#5 on the toolbar. Toolbar belongs to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

you should look into Custom Events.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Idea is, that whenever there is some update of your desire in child component, you can execute `this.$emit(“change”)`, which will throw an event.

On parent side you can catch this event by `@change=“myMethod”` as one of the attributes.

```js
methods: {
  myMethod() {
    console.log("Testing")
  }
}
```

```html
<child-component
          v-for="i in count"
          ref="childComponent"
          :key="i"
          currentPage="i"
          :page="i"
          @change=“myMethod”
/>
```

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have access to the child component as it is a component that I install via npm.